# Write multiple formulas to excel sheet with xlsxwriter in while loop

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

I am trying to populate a formula in multiple cells of a sheet using `xlsxwriter` with Python 2.7.  I need to pass in the formula as a string that includes both single and double quotes as the following:
`'F2','=IF(E2=MIN($E$2:$E$545),E2,"")'` where the row values are stored in variables in the script as `formularowcount` and `rowcount`.

I am getting this exception: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'`.

The code:

```
while rowcount > formularowcount:
profiledatasheet.write_formula("'F"+str(formularowcount)+"','=IF(E"+str(formularowcount)+"=MIN($E$2:$E$"+str(rowcount)+"),E"+str(formularowcount)+",\"""\")'")
```

I've tried to store the string itself and pass it in, but get the same exception:

```
formulavalue = "'F"+str(formularowcount)+"','=IF(E"+str(formularowcount)+"=MIN($E$2:$E$"+str(rowcount)+"),E"+str(formularowcount)+",\"""\")'"
        profiledatasheet.write_formula(formulavalue)
```

However, if I print the string out in debug and paste the output into the debug console, it works and returns 0:

```
print(formulavalue)
'F2','=IF(E2=MIN($E$2:$E$545),E2,"")'

profiledatasheet.write_formula('F2','=IF(E2=MIN($E$2:$E$545),E2,"")')
0
```

Any ideas as to what is wrong with my syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (if you use 3)

```
profiledatasheet.write_formula(
    f'F{formularowcount}',
    f'=IF(E{formularowcount}=MIN($E$2:$E${rowcount}),E{formularowcount},"")'
)
```

For python 2 something like

```
profiledatasheet.write_formula(
'F{0}'.format(formularowcount),
'=IF(E{0}=MIN($E$2:$E${1}),E{0},"")'.format(formularowcount, rowcount)
```

)

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm using python 2.7